# How many system Variable need to be set While installing phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, system-variable

I am installing **phonegap** but at the time of installing there are problems coming in installation. I think I have not set all the `environment variables` in the system . Any body have list of variables.

Thank You

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: @Kedarnath I added all this path still not getting. unable to add android platform

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to install ADT ? Current ADT has problem see this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: ADT is installed problem with adding platform android to it

Answer (score 1):

**User Variables**

Path : `C:\Documents and Settings\avaya11\Application Data\npm`

**System Variables**

ANDROID_HOME : `C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk;`

ANT_HOME : `C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.3`

CLASSPATH : `.;D:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platforms;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platform-tools;`

JAVA_HOME : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

Path : `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\platforms-tools;C:\NEW ANDROID\sdk\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%SystemRoot%\System32;C:\Program Files\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin;`

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32;` for what?

Comment: xcopy.exe is located at system32. It is very important for adding anroid platform for recognizing android SDK.cheers

Comment: yeah xcopy.exe at that location. I added it to my system path. Let me check.